# Adding elements to Listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm implementing my first android app and I want to be able to enter text into a box, hit a button, and have that text displayed in some kind of arbitrarily sized list structure below it.
Currently I have the main fragment's XML set up as:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/msg"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="sendMsg"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="368dp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Should I be decoupling more? Using fragments differently? Are there any design principles I'm overlooking?

Comment: Both TableRow layout_height's are match/fill_parent, which won't work. First should be wrap_content, second should be layout_height="0dp", layout_weight="1". I would personally use nested LinearLayouts in this case instead of the TableLayout but that doesn't matter. Is there a reason that the ListView has a specific size and is not match_parent in both height and width?

Comment: That's how the android studio GUI generated the XML, no reason for the hardcoded values. What would be the benefit of using nested LinearLayouts?

Comment: I have found nested LinearLayouts very versatile. They work well for creating the exact design required that adapts well to different screen sizes. They allow you to easily reorder elements. I use RelativeLayouts with LinearLayouts if I need to overlap elements. I write all my layouts directly in xml and in my experience LinearLayouts result in less code.

Comment: what about if you want an arbitrary number of new LinearLayouts generated when a button is clicked?

Comment: I'd probably use a ListView or GridView with an Adapter. The Adapter would call layout files for each item. See: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html